# PHP redirect not working (based on user agent string)

Tags: php, user-agent

I am running the following redirect script:

```
<?php
$badAgents = array('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0');
if(in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],$badAgents)) {
require("1.php");
} else {
require("2.php");
}
?>
```

However every single visitor is getting sent to "2.php" regardless of their user agent. For example I go in Firefox, I got to 2.php, I go in Internet Explorer, I see 2.php.

Please may someone direct me as to what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you for your time

Comment: You are being too specific by using that agent string. That exact string will only match Firefox 25.0 on Windows 7 x64 (possibly even more specific with the engine revision). Try to broaden your search string. Lookup browser search strings for the best way to do it.

Comment: I used that particular string just as an example, to see if the redirect worked for my computer when visiting in FF, which it did not...

Comment: Try to use function `get_browser`

Comment: Alexander: would you be kind enough to rewrite the code for me based on the "get_browser" function please? My PHP skills don't even qualify as basic :(

Comment: Can you put `echo '::', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], '::', $badAgents[0], '::', PHP_EOL;` before the `if` and show us the exact output

Comment: As @Demonslay335 said, the code will work if the User Agent matches, but it's a really specific string. - If you want to test it, use `echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];` to make sure the browser your using to test is correctly matching.

Answer (score 3):

Check our logic.

Here's the pseudo logic you are using:

- If the user has a bad user agent, then require 1.php.
- If the user does NOT have a bad user agent, then require 2.php.

Unless the user visits your page with exactly the right version of Firefox, the code you're using will not use 1.php.

I would also recommend you change your code as follows:

```
if (stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'firefox') === false) {
    require '2.php';
} else {
    require '1.php';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply and help. However I must be missing something. I updated the code as you say, but now if I visit in FF I go to 1.php, or if I visit in IE I go to 1.php. Same PHP redirect either way.

My point for using such a specific user agent was just as a test on my computer alone

Comment: Alternatively, you can also check against 'firefox/25.0' instead of just 'firefox'.

Comment: This does not explain why the OPs code (he is using his own UA) isn't working.

Comment: It was implied with my statement of "Unless the user visits your page with exactly the right version of Firefox, the code you're using will not use 1.php." But, you're right. I didn't come right out and say, "You're probably not checking against the correct UA."

Answer (score 0):

Your String is a bit to long to match. It's better when you only filter for a short but explicit string like **Firefox**.

```
<?php
if(stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'firefox') !== false)) {
    require("1.php");
} else {
    require("2.php");
}
?>
```

Then your change is bigger that the "rule" match.

The second is that there are some functions to parse the User agent like **[get_browser](http://php.net/manual/de/function.get-browser.php)** and you get a better result to work with.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, however now everything is going to 2.php again, regardless of if I use Firefox or IE.

Here's the thing though... I have 7 very specific user agents I want to block on my site... I'm not using this for the average visitor

Comment: Try strtolower to lower all input of HTTP_USER_AGENT. Perhaps you should implement some test outputs to see if the string match or not and whats the input values.

Comment: ``Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; de-DE; rv:1.7. Gecko/20050511 Firefox/1.0.4`` This is a normal user Agent string. At the end of the Firefox string is **Firefox** and the Version.

Comment: Yes right sorry... I haven't send my edit.. in_array isn't working here... if you need really an array you can try array_search. But with stripos its much easiert.